# Reading RSS feed with AngularJS and displaying results conditionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rss

This may be beyond the scope and capability of AngularJS, but I'm putting it out there in hope. Is it possible to read from an RSS feed every 30 seconds in AngularJS and have it bind the latest 10 results with a category id of 'X' to a model or data collection?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, Yes.

You can create a `service` module for pulling the RSS and you can call the service in the `controller`, or schedule it. Angularjs is 2-way binding, and as long as the data is updated in the scope, it will be rendered to the template automatically.